# Override class member values without changing actual implemetation

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have class like following :

```
class SignalProcessor
{
  //....

  bool memberBool;
  uint32_t memberUint32;

  int memberArray[10];
  //...
  float memberfloat;
};
```

`SignalProcessor` implementation is for a control system, with some complex algorithm.

Now I have to override ***some*** of those member values with some other values coming from another application for *diagnostic/debugging* purposes.

One way would be to dirty the entire implementation with bunch of `#ifdef` or `if... else..` every where in the code.

So I was curious if I could do anything only within the SignalProcessor header to override those values, something like following.

```
SignalOverride< bool, true > memberBool;
SignalOverride< uint32_t, false> memberUint32;
SignalOverride< int, true> memberArray[10];

// SignalOverride 
template <typename T, bool overrideOn >
class  SignalOverride
{
   T operator=(const T& value )
   {
      if( !overrideOn )
      {
         m_signal = value;
      }
      else
      {
         /* m_signal =  ???
          Not entirely sure how to assign values here from other  application.
         */
      }
      return *this;
   }

   operator T () const
   {
      return m_signal ;
   }   

   // ...
   private:
    T m_signal;
}
```

The other application has same signal names in couple of C structs like following, which somehow I would have to use if override option is true.

```
struct Values1
{
  bool memberBool;
  uint32_t memberUint32;   
};

struct Values2
{
  int memberArray[10];   
};
```

I am open to any other design/solutions, except I don't want to go through each place in several source files and do `if...else...`

<sub>**I can only use *`C++98`*** ( poor me )</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your first task is to actually find out "how to assign values here from other  application", because until you've done that this entire question is absolutely moot.

But assuming it turns out you can just name an object as you do now, `#ifdef` is indeed the conventional way to do this. `if` is going to make a much worse mess *and* have runtime detriments. And these are your only real options (without some super-massive magic class hierarchy with entirely unreadable template metahackery) because C++ doesn't support overriding of *data* members.

So just go for it with `#ifdef`.

And if you find that you have too many places in which to write `#ifdef`, perhaps that's a sign that:

- this "mode" is too widespread and should in fact be a separate application, or
- your classes are not properly isolated from each other.